# What counts as billable data transfer in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

What counts as billable data transfer? It is apparently data that transfers **out** of the data centre but what is that exactly?

If a SQL Azure database is queried by a web role in the same region is the data going from the SQL Azure database to the web role billed for?

Is data from a same region storage account to a web role billed? If so what about in the same affinity group?

Is bandwidth from the web role itself down to the user billed? E.g. images stored as part of the solution being viewed by lots of people.

Is the data transferred during a remote desktop session billed? I.e. literally the bandwidth used to actually see an instance's desktop via RDP, not anything downloaded from that instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If a SQL Azure database is queried by a web role in the same region is
>   the data going from the SQL Azure database to the web role billed for?

No. This transfer will not be billed. But only if the region is specific (i.e. North Europe, but not Anywhere Europe). The data stays within the same data center.

> Is data from a same region storage account to a web role billed? If so
>   what about in the same affinity group?

No. This transfer is not billed. Again meaning specific Region, and not Generic region (anywhere ****). As for Hosted Service and Storage Account in same affinity group - it will also not be billed. The data stays within the same Data Center.

> Is bandwidth from the web role itself down to the user billed? E.g.
>   images stored as part of the solution being viewed by lots of people.

Yes. This is Out transfer which is being billed. The data is going out of the Data Center.

> Is the data transferred during a remote desktop session billed? I.e.
>   literally the bandwidth used to actually see an instance's desktop via
>   RDP, not anything downloaded from that instance.

Yes, this transfer will be billed. But only the outbound traffic. You know that RDP session is two way communication. Only the part which is outward the Data Center will be billed, not the inbound traffic. There is data traffic (TCP packets) going out of the data center.

Comment: Thanks. This is all logical. I just wanted a definitive answer to these questions as I couldn't find clarification anywhere

Comment: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/#data-transfer - could it be clearer? :)

Comment: The only addition to what you've said is that if you create an affinity group in a generic region (anywhere Europe for example) then data transfers between storage accounts and compute instances in that affinity group will not be billable

Comment: @Matthew, agree, but there was another question especially for Affinity groups and we concluded that one shall always explicitly point concrete location, even for an Afinity group, because SQL Azure and Service Bus does not use affinity groups, but just specific locations.

Comment: @astaykov, yes that makes sense. Still haven't managed to work out why SQL Azure etc don't use affinity groups. They're a great idea for those of us that don't mind which datacentre we're going to use (and would allow Microsoft to load-balance on a larger scale!)